# New struts on a 2000 model year car with 225k miles, replace coils?

Tags: toyota, suspension, springs, celica

Should the suspension coil springs be replaced on a Toyota Celica that is 15 years old and has 225k along with the struts or do the coils never really go bad?

How about the top bearing plate?

Comment: Depends , how is your ride quality? is it bumpy? or spongy? there is no reason to change anything unless it is not working as expected..

Comment: right strut is leaking car feels bumps rough, when I do a bounce test it doesn't bounce much, front seem a bit lower then the rear but I assume that's normal?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some points which you should look for in your suspension to determine whether you need to change them or not.

**1. Bumpy Ride**

Drive the car on some rough roads, if you can feel all of the slightest bumps then unfortunately your coils are wearing out and you need to fix them.
Also drive on a pothole in low speed, does your suspension does full travel? if so then you need to replace them.

**2. Stop test**

Drive at about 25mph and hit the brakes hard, if your car rocks back and forth or it nose dives then you need to have a look at your suspension.

**3. Oil leakage**

Look carefully at your dampers, are there any noticeable leaks on them , then you need to address that.

**4. The Bounce Test**

This is by far the easiest way to know if your suspension is working fine.

- Stand near the front wheel arch, press against the bonnet.
- On realease if your car bounces 2 or three times and slowly fades the bouncing effect then your suspensions are shot.
- If on realease they dont bounce at all then same, check suspension.
- However, if on release it bounces approximately 2 times and stops bouncing quickly then your suspension is fine, do it for all 4 wheels.

After doing all the above tests , you can be sure if you need to replace them or not.

Answer (score 1):

The only time springs usually go bad is if the shocks/struts are no longer functioning. If a vehicle has bad shock/struts and is allowed to bounce all over the place, the springs become worn out. If the shocks/struts are replaced when required, you should have no fear of the springs.

You can always do an inspection of the springs. Reasons to replace them:

- If they are deformed in anyway (leaning to the side or bulging in the middle)
- If after alignment, one side of the vehicle is leaning when on level ground (you can also measure from the wheel well to the tire on either side to get a better idea - bounce the car several times prior to settle the car)
- If they are broken. Sometimes extreme abuse can cause the springs to break. You'd probably know this if it happened.

Assuming you mean the top mount of a strut when you said *bearing plate*, this should be replaced if worn. It should be fairly self evident if it is (cracks and holes).